# He's worried himself sick about his daughter

Tags: tense, contractions

**He's worried himself sick about his daughter.**
In this sentence, Is either He's [He is] or [He has] ?

Comment: You can say **He is worried sick** but if you're describing a process which has ended in that result, it is as the answers say, **He has worried himself sick**.

Comment: There is a difference between saying **He is in this state** and **He has done things to get himself into this state**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **He has**.  This sentence is an example of the [present perfect tense](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/).  The present perfect is formed with *to have* (here, **He has**) and a past participle (here, **worried**).

You're probably asking "Why can't it be *is*?" because "He is worried" is also a perfectly good sentence.  The answer is that if it were *is*, then "worried himself sick" doesn't make sense, so it must be *has*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can only be "He has". "He is worried himself sick about his daughter" is ungrammatical and makes no sense. To worry oneself sick means to become ill through worry.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%E2%80%94_oneself_sick